# Expect-CT header: Is needed something special for report-uri?

Tags: web-server, http-headers

I've was reading about the Expect-CT header (e.g. : [Expect-CT - A new HTTP Security Header to be aware of](https://www.ryadel.com/en/expect-ct-http-header-security-chrome/#Apache)
),

For example in Apache:

`Expect-CT: max-age=0, report-uri="https://www.example.com/report"`

It just only something about configuration? Perhaps, I didn't fully understand the meaning of **report-uri**

Should I code/configure something for report-uri in the web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser will send reports about CT failures (as independent HTTP requests) to the `report-uri`. Some software running at that URI should record the report and help you in evaluating errors. I am using the [report-uri.com](https://report-uri.com/) service for that, but of course you can build it yourself if you want to.

*(Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with report-uri.com in any way, just a happy user.)*